# Send email in PHP that contains a link, which then triggers a POST request?

Tags: php

So i have some code that is sending an email to a user. The email contains a link which allows the user to change their password if they have forgotten it. The code works fine and sends the email. When i click the link it sends a GET request that contains the email of the user in the URL. Im just curious, is there a way to alter the code in php so when it sends the email the link in the email then sends a POST request. With the email of the user inside the POST body? Here is the code that is currently sending the email. Im not even sure if what im asking is possible.

```
$link = "http://localhost/myphp/talkbook2/forgotpassword/ResetPassword.php?Email=".$email;
$title = "Please click this link to reset your password";
$subject = "Reset Password";
$message = "<a href='". $link. "'>".$title. "</a>\n\n";
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0". "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1". "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: TalkBook". "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: talkbookapp@gmail.com". "\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: talkbookapp@gmail.com". " \r\n";

if(!isset($_SESSION['passwordEmailSent']) && empty($_SESSION['passwordEmailSent']))
{
    $send = mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
    $_SESSION['passwordEmailSent'] = 1;
}
else
{
    $send = false;
}

return $send;
```

Comment: -Machavity This is not a duplicate to that question.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a html form in email and   `action="http://yourdomain.com/post.php"` and `method="post"` also you can use input type=hidden for saving that field. or use some field and set visibility to hidden. and populate those fields with values.

Comment: So send the form in the email then let the user fill it out there? Is there is no way to directly send a single link in an email that will trigger a post when clicked?